# How to save data into database using HttpGet in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-get

I know its not a good practice to save data using `HttpGet`, rather than we should use `HttpPost`, but if I want to achieve the same using `HttpGet` with an action method of my ASP.NET MVC controller, how can I do that?

Comment: And how do you plan to pass the data changed by the user to your server side code? Please show an example of what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You really should try to keep the good practices!
But assuming that you want to pass data in the body of the request, I believe you can do something like this:

> ```
>     [HttpGet] 
>     [AllowAnonymous] 
>     public IActionResult RequestMethod([FromBody]RequestModel myModel) {
>         if (myModel == null)
>         {
>               return BadRequest();
>         }
>
>         // your logic here
>     }
> ```

The FromBody annotation allows you to add a body to the HTTP GET